# Why ISINSCOPE not returning BLANK as expected?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Why is it that **ISINSCOPE** does not work in my case?

I have this measure:

[image]

I am expecting to see BLANK in all levels except **GroupName**, but I see 1, I can't figure out why.

My expected output is:
[image]

(That is, it should be BLANK for all rows, except at the GroupName Level)

In the visual I am pulling:

[image]

Code is:

```
NumberofBU = 
IF (
    ISINSCOPE(AllADGroupMembers[GroupName]), 
    SUMX(DISTINCT(Employee[Business]),1),
    BLANK()
)
```

Comment: Can you please add some sample data with your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

You don`t use **ISINSCOPE()** correctly: all your *Businesses* are in scope of *GroupNames* so you simply count distinct *Businesses* for each row.
To get your desired result try something like:

```
NumberofBU = 
IF (
    ISFILTERED(Employee[Business]),
    BLANK(),
    SUMX(DISTINCT(Employee[Business]),1)
)
```

To learn more about **ISFILTERED()** function visit [DAX Guide](https://dax.guide/isfiltered/).